# A subvector of a gaussian vector is gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I need to demonstrate that a subvector of a gaussian vector is gaussian, but I don't really understand the difference between a gaussian multivariate and normal multivariate vector, I believe they are the same and that every affine transformation of a gaussian vector is gaussian, so I would appreciate if someone can explain this to me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: For starters, what is a "subvector"?

Comment: "Normal" and "Gaussian" are typically synonyms.  Can you find an affine transform that will take your first Gaussian vector and produce the desired subvector?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes, it exists an affine transformation that transforms the first vector in the other subvector. I mean
$$(x_1,...,x_m) = A (y_1,..., y_n)^t + (b_1,...,b_n)$$ where  $A$ is an $n,m$ matrix.

Comment: What do you know about affine transformations of multivariate normal vectors?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I only know that in many books they take that one as the definition but if we take as definition that a vector is normal multivariate if its probability density function is the one of a normal multivariate (when the nxn matrix is non-degenerate and positive definite) but I don't know what about the case if it's a nxm matrix